# Error/Warning using the replicate function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate the station number 24 times each by using the code as follows:

```
stnid <- NULL

for (i in 1:24) {
  stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station",i),times=24)
}

> stnid
 [1] "station1"  "station2"  "station3"  "station4"  "station5"  "station6"  "station7"  "station8"  "station9" 
[10] "station10" "station11" "station12" "station13" "station14" "station15" "station16" "station17" "station18"
[19] "station19" "station20" "station21" "station22" "station23" "station24"
```

However, I get the warnings saying :

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
6: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
7: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
8: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
9: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
10: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
11: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
12: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
13: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
14: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
15: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
16: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
17: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
18: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
19: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
20: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
21: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
22: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
23: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
24: In stnid[i] <- rep(paste0("station", i), times = 24) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Could anyone explain what did I do wrong here ? Thanks.

**Expected:**

each station from station 1 to station24 24 times each.

Comment: You are trying to assign a character vector of length 24 to a single vector element; R doesn't allow this.  You could, among other possibilities, (1) use a 24-column matrix; (2) use a list; (3) `paste` the results together using the `collapse` argument; (4, @Henrik's answer) create a vector of length 24*24. What, precisely, do you want the structure of your result to be?  Can you show a small example where you hand-construct the answer (say make it '"station1" to "station3" 3 times each')?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for your comments. The answer by Henrik is exactly what I wanted to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
rep(x = paste0("station", 1:24), times = 24)
```

Or if you rather want stations with the same number to occur together:

```
rep(x = paste0("station", 1:24), each = 24)
```

Comment: +1 Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't realize it was so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This would have created a 24 element list each of whose elements was a 24 length vector:

```
stnid <- list()

for (i in 1:24) {
  stnid[[i]] <- rep(paste0("station",i),times=24)
}

 stnid
```